# Importing XML captions from String to Project

Tags: javascript, plugins, jsx, adobe

I'm writing a Premiere Pro plugin that grabs Premiere XML captions and I'm interested in importing them directly to the opened project using CsInterface.

But I had only found a way to do so by the `importFiles` function, while I haven't found a way to save my XML into a File so I can not import it that way.

What can I do?
Thanks in advance everyone